# blow-ups of secant varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve embedded in ${\mathbb P}^n$ by a full linear system  (I am particularly interested in the case of an elliptic curve but it seems natural to ask the question in more generality). Let $S_k$ be the $k$-th secant variety, i.e. the union of all $k$ planes 
intersecting $C$ at (at least) $k+1$ points. Construct $X_k$ inductively:
$X_1$ is the blow-up of ${\mathbb P}^n$ along $C$, $X_2$ is the blow-up of $X_1$ along the proper preimage of $S_1$ in $X_1$ etc. Is there a reasonable moduli interpretation for $X_i$, especially for the last one $X_d$, $d=[(n-3)/2]$?
For a particular value of $n$ Bertram identified $X_d$ (or something similar) with the 
moduli space of semi-stable rank 2 vector bundles on $C$; but I am interested in the case
of an arbitrary $n$.

Comment: What does "$X_1$ is the blow-up of $C$" mean? Did you intend to say "the blow-up of $\mathbb P^1$ at $C$"?

Comment: @Will -- I think the OP means the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along the ideal sheaf of the embedded curve $C$.

Comment: yes, I meant blow up of ${\mathbb P}^n$ along $C$, sorry about the imprecise wording

Comment: wording corrected

Comment: I think this is very hard.  Bertram in his range is able to prove that $X_k$ is smooth away from $X_{k-1}$.  This will not be true in general. 

Comment: Can you give an example when X_k isn't smooth? -- thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can probaly describe your space as some kind of fibration in $\mathcal{M}_{0,m}$ over the dual linear system $\mathbb{P}^{n*}$, via Kapranov's blow-up construction of $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{0,m}}$ . This is done in

http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5515

for some of the Bertram's cases but it should hold in general. Your space may have an interpretation in terms of moduli of vector bunldes (or sheaves).